# Updating Icons after a QResource::registerResource()

Tags: c++, qt

I have a program that changes the resources file on the fly (`QResource::registerResource()`) successfully.

The problem is that my icons aren't changing automatically.

I've implemented a few solutions which work, but none of them seemed really good for me...

Take a look:

#### Solution 1

It isn't a really bad solution, but it's so handmade for me. This project has a lot of Icons

```
QPixmap pix(":/images/save");
QIcon icon(pix);
ui->myBtn->setIcon(icon);
```

#### Solutuion 2

Really bad, performance issues, also too handmade.

```
QObject::disconnect(ui->myBtn, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(changeResources()));
ui->setupUi(this);
QObject::connect(ui->myBtn, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(changeResources()));
```

---

I thought calling the window's `QWidget::update()` method would do the job but unfortunately, no.

Is there some smarter solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution that we've found is to create an `IconManager`, which handles all icons from our application.

To create and apply an icon we use `IconManager::create(QWidget *widget, QString iconPath);`

And then, when we need to update all Icons we call `IconManager::refreshAll();`

Inside of it we have a map between the widget and iconPath, and when called `refreshAll` we do something similiar to

```
for (std::map<QWidget*, String>::iterator it = Map.begin(); it != Map.end(); ++it)
{
    QPixmap pix(it->second);
    QIcon icon(pix);
    it->first->setIcon(icon);
}
```